# Проблема запуска автотестов с помощью Jenkins, в чем может быть ошибка?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, selenide

Правая моя попытка знакомства с Jenkins. В intellij idea тесты прогоняются, но как только пытаюсь запустить их через Jenkins с помощью maven 3.9.2(clean test), появляется ошибка:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project fck-autotests: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Class com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCImport does not have member field 'com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree qualid' -> [Help 1]
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> [ERROR] [Help 1]

Если нужно то вот pom проекта

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

```
<groupId>itf-internship</groupId>
<artifactId>fck-autotests</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.9.1</aspectj.version>
    <allure.version>2.21.0</allure.version>
    <allure-junit5.version>2.21.0</allure-junit5.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wiremock</groupId>
        <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wiremock</groupId>
        <artifactId>wiremock-standalone</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--для рандомных значений-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.7.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--для работы с бд-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-selenide</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-rest-assured -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>2.24.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.20.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- для генерации рандомных строк -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.24.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
        <version>${allure-junit5.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
        <version>6.19.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-reload4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.28</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.source}</target>
                <parameters>true</parameters>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
                </argLine>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <allure.results.directory>${project.basedir}/target/allure-results</allure.results.directory>
                    <selenide.browser>chrome</selenide.browser>
                    <selenide.reportsFolder>${project.basedir}/target/screenshots</selenide.reportsFolder>
                    <!--для корректной работы в Jenkins необходимо поставить headless = true-->
                    <selenide.headless>true</selenide.headless>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>io.qameta.allure.junit5.AllureJunit5</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportVersion>${allure.version}</reportVersion>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Какая версия JDK используется на стороне Jenkins?  Похожие проблемы описаны на основном SO [при переходе на Java 21 в сочетании с использованием Lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77171270/)